# How to label sequential data for LSTM usage

Tags: pandas, sequence, lstm

I want to process data to feed it to a LSTM later, each 100 rows correspond to single category how should I label the data? Should I concatenate the 100 rows into a single row?
Data Sample:-

```
,emg1,emg2,emg3,emg4,emg5,emg6,emg7,emg8,quat1,quat2,quat3,quat4,acc1,acc2,acc3,gyro1,gyro2,gyro3
0,81,342,283,146,39,71,36,31,1121,-2490,930,16128,-797,4,2274,49,2920,252
0,70,323,259,125,34,53,29,31,1055,-3112,1075,16015,-878,369,1830,516,3590,243
0,53,298,246,100,49,37,27,33,1019,-3792,1239,15858,-809,527,1511,632,3953,46
0,42,154,193,172,95,48,28,28,1018,-4433,1360,15681,-724,358,1235,486,3754,-183
0,41,150,179,242,225,76,51,43,1066,-4980,1464,15503,-827,176,1073,525,3209,-415
...
```

Comment: You have to label each row and then perform train and test split.

Comment: @SrivasanSridharan so adding an extra column with the right label is enough? and how will the model know that each 100 row represents a single label?

Comment: while training the model you give input and label to the model to train. model.fit(x,y) where x is the input and y will be your labels.